# Sharepoint 2013 Dec CU

Tags: upgrade

Does anyone know where I can download the 2013 December CU from - Microsoft site says the page is unavailable [kb2910938](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2910938)

Comment: The link you posted is for December 9, 2014 Cumulative Update for SharePoint Server 2013 package. And it works fine.

Comment: yes the link works - but try to download the file - you will probably get a sorry page unavailable message

Comment: Have you tried link given in below answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the same CU from below mentioned link. As I am able to download it from this link.

[December 9, 2014 Cumulative Update for SharePoint Server 2013 package](https://support.microsoft.com/sr-latn-me/kb/2910938)

**Important notes about the cumulative update package**

- The Microsoft Office 2013 hotfixes are **now multilingual**. This cumulative update package **contains updates for all languages**.
- This cumulative update package includes all the server component packages. Additionally, this cumulative update package updates only those components that are installed on the system.

**UPDATED**

There was an issue in Microsoft site yesterday. I had tried it today & links for same CU download are working fine.

Comment: this still doesn't work for me  on any browser or another machine are you  able to download and upload somewhere where I can download it?

Comment: I had tried to download to confirm & then after cancelled it. Now it is showing the same error to me as well... Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: If you wish than you can download the Feb 2015 update which will probably include all Dec 2014 hotfix fixes.. from here...https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45822

Comment: unfortunately I cannot upgrade to newer CU as I am trying to match another server's version level (which I cannot upgrade higher the Dec 2014 CU which its already on)

Comment: You need to wait as there is something wrong with Microsoft site as mentioned there while downloading the CU. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the above link is fixed now, I tried to download it and it take me to the download page and once i enter the required information, within 5 min, I get the download link in the email.

this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/hotfix/kbhotfix?kbnum=2910938&kbln=en-us)

See the link.

[image]

If you still getting the error, try from different computer.